# TEE vs SharedPreferences в разработке android

Tags: android, безопасность

Вопрос довольно простой - что лучше TEE или настройки приложения sharedPreferences. На текущий момент я разрабатываю приложение которое связывается с сервером для получения/отправки данных, короче обычный клиент-сервер. Для того чтобы отправить/получить данные я использую токены которые хранятся в памяти устройства SharedPreferences. Но на мой взгляд история с sharedPreferences немного проигрывает потому что при наличии рут доступа можно спокойно взять все что угодно из памяти устройства. Дальше немного теории:

> Безопасная среда исполнения (Trusted Execution Environment, TEE)
>   характеризуется защищенностью, контролем целостности и наличием
>   собственной оперативной памяти и пространства хранения. Она
>   изолирована от обычной «функционально богатой среды исполнения» (Rich
>   Execution Environment, REE), в которой работают операционная система и
>   приложения мобильного устройства.

вот [ссылка](https://www.osp.ru/os/2014/08/13043488/) может кому будет интересно почитать про TEE. Этот вопрос задается для того чтобы понять имеет ли смысл запариться и сделать к примеру авторизацию через отпечаток пальца или же не мучиться и использовать логин/пароль как и раньше. Так же довольно интересный вопрос - как например туда забросить данные типа токена или это невозможно. Возьмем живой пример - приложение для банкинга (Приват24 или Сбербанк не суть) пользователь выбрал как способ входа приложить свой палец к нужному месту на экране и дальше он получает доступ к своим счетам. До сегодня я получал всю нужную мне информацию посредством отправки токена на определенный адрес и все, но при прикладывании пальца дается ли мне токен или же там как-то иначе все начинает работать? Может кто-то работал с такой темой и может мне посоветовать куда копать и стоит ли копать вообще :)

P.S. Возможно заголовок немного нужно отредактировать, если что предлагайте свои варианты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я копал. Лучше конечно смотреть в сторону TEE, есть либа [RxFingerPrint](https://github.com/Mauin/RxFingerprint), которая умеет с помощью ключа аутентификации отпечатка складывать в защищенный KeyStore данные.

И что немаловажно все сделано в идеологии RxJava - мелочь, а приятно.

Comment: а токены например хранить там можно как-то?

Comment: мой предыдущий вопрос можно задать более нормально - можно ли пользоваться tee так же как и sharedpreferences? то есть положить туда что-то а потом в нужный момент взять оттуда что-то? ну и так же соответственно за отпечаток )

Comment: Не обратили внимание на опус: *которая умеет с помощью ключа аутентификации отпечатка складывать в защищенный KeyStore данные* - да вполне аналогично `SharedPreferences` и в конце то концов возьмите в руки саму либу и прочтите ее краткие мануалы - потратьте 10 минут